# Why the file has 0755, but 'Permission denied'?

Tags: 14.04, permissions, filesystem, root, ruby

Why the file has 0755, but I got an error 'Permission denied'?

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin# ls -la
total 14000
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Feb  9 20:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root     4096 Feb  9 20:25 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     4861 Feb  9 20:25 erb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      565 Feb  9 20:25 gem
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      209 Feb  9 20:25 irb
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     1263 Feb  9 20:25 rake
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      957 Feb  9 20:25 rdoc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      207 Feb  9 20:25 ri
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14295306 Feb  9 20:23 ruby

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/erb
-bash: /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/erb: Permission denied
```

Comment: What's the output of `namei -m /root/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/bin/erb`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "vagrant" user will not have permissions to do anything in /root because it will have 0700 perms. Therefore anything in /root or in any subdirectory under /root etc will not be accessible by any use other than root. Prefix it with sudo and it should work.

This is the correct setup and I strongly recommend that you leave /root's perms as 0700. Don't chmod 0755 to make that command work or anything.

Comment: I know, that it will work with `sudo`. But why `vagrant` user can't execute the file, that's executable for `others` (last `x`)?

Comment: @DmitryR i updated my answer to provide more info

Comment: Thanks, got it. We can't access files if upper directories don't have `x` flag.

Comment: The execute bit on directories refers more to the ability to traverse that directory. EG if you chmod a directory to 0744 people will be able to ls that directory but can't cd into it etc.